# Polygon GeoJSON Features Will Load in Console But Will Not Display in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

GIS data and python are old hat to me but I am very new to web development and geospatial web applications.

I have followed a tutorial and a class that I am taking to get to the below script but I cannot get the resulting geojson object (the polygon layer) to display within leaflet. I can however, log all of the features of the polygon layer to the console. Furthermore, within the console I can clearly see the correct type, properties, and coordinate arrays of the geojson object. I can also clearly see all of the features within the leaflet map object within the console.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. If needed I will be happy to post the getData.php code. I just don't think that is the problem.

```
var map,
            fieldsin = ["campus_nam", "status", "schnumber", "type"],
            autocomplete = [];

        $(document).ready(initialize);

        function initialize(){
            map = L.map("mapdiv", {
                center: [36.10, -80.25],
                zoom: 12
            });
            var backgroundLayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

            //adding postgresql layers to map with getData.php
            getData(fieldsin);
        };

        function getData(fieldsin){
            $.ajax({
                url: "php/getData.php",
                data: { table: "public.school_campus", fields: fieldsin },
                success: function(data){
                    mapData(data);
                }
            })
        };
        function mapData(data){
            //remove existing map layers
            map.eachLayer(function(layer){
                //if not the tile layer
                if (typeof layer._url === "undefined"){
                    map.removeLayer(layer);
                }
            })

            //create geojson container object
            var geojson = {
                "type": "FeatureCollection",
                "features": []
            };

            //split data into features
            var dataArray = data.split(", ;");
            //pop off the last value of the array because it is an empty string.
            dataArray.pop();
            //build geojson features
            dataArray.forEach(function(d){

                d = d.split(", "); //split the comma seperated data string up into individual attribute values
                var test = d[fieldsin.length].concat("}");

                //feature object container
                var feature = {
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {}, //properties object container
                    //"geometry": JSON.parse(d[fieldsin.length]) //parse geometry
                    "geometry": JSON.parse(d[fieldsin.length]) //parse geometry
                };

                //bulding properties for properties container above
                for (var i=0; i<fieldsin.length; i++){
                    feature.properties[fieldsin[i]] = d[i];
                };

                //add feature names to autocomplete list
                if ($.inArray(feature.properties.campus_nam, autocomplete) == -1){
                    autocomplete.push(feature.properties.campus_nam);
                };

                //console.log(feature.geometry)

                geojson.features.push(feature);

                //var campusLayer = L.geoJSON(geojson).addTo(map);
                var campusLayer = L.geoJSON(geojson, {
                    style: {
                        fillColor: "#CC9900",
                        color: "#66ffff",
                        weight: 1
                    },
                    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                        var html = "";
                        for (prop in feature.properties){
                            html += prop+": "+feature.properties[prop]+"<br>";
                        };
                        layer.bindPopup(html);
                    }
                }).addTo(map);
            });
        };
```

Comment: I suggest running your generated GeoJSON through http://geojsonlint.com/ . That might uncover errors you might not be aware of.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a sample of your resulting GeoJSON object would have surely helped in understanding your situation.

However I highly suspect that you have simply inverted the coordinates:

- Leaflet expects `[latitude, longitude]` order
- GeoJSON expects `[longitude, latitude]` order

See also https://macwright.org/lonlat/

Therefore there is a very high chance your Leaflet GeoJSON Layer Group is actually added onto your map, but you would have to zoom out to see your features on a completely different place and distorded.

Looks like you also have not specified the appropriate [CRS](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#crs) to your Leaflet map instance, or you need to convert the coordinates from your backend to the Leaflet's default [EPSG:3857](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#crs-l-crs-epsg3857).

Note that the GeoJSON spec [requests WGS84 CRS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-4), which is the same input for EPSG:3857.

Comment: The GeoJSON feature objects are pretty big. For instance the first one that comes up is 60 arrays of coordinates. In the php file (not posted) I call upon "ST_ASGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geom))" to create the geojson geometry from the postgis table. I can't find in the documentation for that tool if it actually flips the coordinates for you but I would imagine that it would.. Am I wrong there?

Comment: "The GeoJSON feature objects are pretty big": I have no doubt about it. Still, I am sure you can provide a **sample**. Just in case, make sure you go through the [help for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), in particular about providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Here is one of the resulting coordinate arrays: [1639085.50275818, 864314.749908417]. It is not in the decimal degrees format that I am used to, but I have tested coordinates like these in QGIS and they draw correctly.

Comment: ghybs You are right! I just looked at the coordinates again in QGIS and they are flipped. Thank you for this! If this ends up being the fix I will post immediately to let you know.

Comment: Looks like you also need to adjust the CRS. See the edited answer.

Comment: I am still working on flipping the coordinates but I have another question about the CRS. I am using the CRS that correctly matches what is in my postgis database (2264). Does the CRS have to be converted to match the leaflet default?

Comment: That is the simplest approach, since most Tile Servers (typically OSM) are in EPSG:3857. Otherwise you would have to look for a Tile Servers that serves tiles projected to your specific CRS.

Comment: @Justin The GeoJSON standard specifies that you **must** use EPSG:4326 (or WGS84 in plain latitude-longitude) for your coordinates. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-4

Comment: @IvanSanchez Simply switching to EPSG:4326 did the trick. I did not have to switch the coordinates at all. As soon as I did that the polygons drew. You are the best!

Comment: @ghybs Thank you so much for helping me work through this as well. This saved hours of headache!